# In Android performance analysis, cup performs a large number of tasks app_ process32_ x

Tags: java, android, systrace

nexus 5,android 6.0.1
lg devices

My list is scrolling

It is found that the frame is lost and the dequeuebuffer takes a long time sh

[dequeuebuffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGJ7N.png)

cpu area：

[cpu area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LqpA.png)

No app found_ process32_  x

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70299046/edit) your post to include device/emulator (and if on Custom ROM/rooted), what the app does and what the app should have been doing at the time.

Comment: It has been updated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.